# Resource bundle editor installed but not working on Eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, resourcebundle

I have installed the **ResourceBundle Editor** plugin (http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/) the usual way. In the plugins folder there's the JAR com.essiembre.eclipse.rbe_1.0.6.jar, in the features folder there's the sub folder com.essiembre.eclipse.rbe_1.0.6 with only the feature.xml in it.

The problem is:

I neither get the **RIGHT-CLICK on properties file** -> **Open with...** -> **ResourceBundle Editor** entry nor do I get any preferences as depicted on http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/ ...

[image]

The above menu entry is *missing entirely*, even though **Help** -> **Install new software...** repeatedly tells me the plugin was/is installed.

**Any ideas what's going on and how to fix this?**

PS: I think programming tools questions belong here... (?)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new file association with the ResourceBundle Editor

1. Go to Preferences > General > Content Types.
2. Add a content type: click "Add Root..." and choose a name you want, e.g. "Properties files"
3. Add a file association: click "Add..." and type "*.properties" (without quotes).
4. Add an associated editor: click "Add..." and choose "ResourceBundle Editor"
5. Apply and close.